# Shared variable between different executables in Linux

Tags: linux, process, fork, mmap, execv

What I want to do is to create a globally shared variable to be accessed by different processes. I want the child process to be replaced by an existing executable.

**UPDATE:** I think this is the solution. The code is borrowed from [here](http://www.jimscode.ca/index.php/component/content/article/13-c/45-c-simple-mmap-example). But since every process needs at least one I/O operation to mmap the file, is there any faster approach?

mycode.h

```
static void* addr; //static
```

app1.cc

## include

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 

int main(void)
{
    size_t length = 1024 * 1024;
    off_t offset = 0;
    int prot = (PROT_READ| PROT_WRITE);
    int flags = MAP_SHARED;
    int fd = -1;

    fd = open("./jim.mymemory", O_RDWR| O_CREAT, S_IRUSR| S_IWUSR );
    if (fd == 0) {
        int myerr = errno;
        printf("ERROR: open failed (errno %d %s)\n", myerr, strerror(myerr));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    addr = mmap(NULL, length, prot, flags, fd, offset);
    if (addr == 0) {
        int myerr = errno;
        printf("ERROR (child): mmap failed (errno %d %s)\n", myerr,
                strerror(myerr));
    }
    *((int *) addr)=5;
if (munmap(addr, length) == -1) {
        int myerr = errno;
        printf("ERROR (child): munmap failed (errno %d %s)\n", myerr,
                strerror(myerr));
    }    
return 0;
}
```

mycode.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "mycode.h"

int main(void) {
    size_t length = 1024 * 1024;
    off_t offset = 0;
    int prot = (PROT_READ| PROT_WRITE);
    int flags = MAP_SHARED;
    int fd = -1;
    pid_t pid;

    fd = open("./jim.mymemory", O_RDWR| O_CREAT, S_IRUSR| S_IWUSR );
    if (fd == 0) {
        int myerr = errno;
        printf("ERROR: open failed (errno %d %s)\n", myerr, strerror(myerr));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (lseek(fd, length - 1, SEEK_SET) == -1) {
        int myerr = errno;
        printf("ERROR: lseek failed (errno %d %s)\n", myerr, strerror(myerr));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    write(fd, "", 1);

    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) { // child
        /*Child process*/

        printf("INFO (child): start \n");
        execv("./app1", NULL); // **app1**
        printf("INFO (child): done \n");

        msync(addr,sizeof(int),MS_SYNC|MS_INVALIDATE); // can  be commented out, since we wait in the parent process

    } else {
        /*Parent process*/
        unsigned int readval = 0;
        addr = mmap(NULL, length, prot, flags, fd, offset);
        if (addr == 0) {
            int myerr = errno;
            printf("ERROR (parent): mmap failed (errno %d %s)\n", myerr,
                    strerror(myerr));
        }

        printf("INFO (parent): start read\n");
        wait(NULL);
        readval = *((int *) addr);
        printf("val: %d \n", readval);
        printf("INFO (parent): done read\n");

        if (munmap(addr, length) == -1) {
            int myerr = errno;
            printf("ERROR (parent): munmap failed (errno %d %s)\n", myerr,
                    strerror(myerr));
        }
    }

    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        int myerr = errno;
        printf("ERROR: close failed (errno %d %s)\n", myerr, strerror(myerr));
    }
    unlink ("./jim.mymemory");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of creating an anonymous mmap, you could use a real file.

Comment: @VaughnCato: thanks. but would it be possible to do something like this?`struct Costume_Struct* my_struct;` and then in the processes `addr = mmap(NULL, length, prot, flags, fd, offset); Costume_Struct* proc_struct = (Costume_Struct*) addr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `execve` will drop all mappings in the kernel, so this technique will not work.  What you can do instead is open a file (as in Vaughn's suggestion) and pass the **descriptor** to the child process.  Open file descriptors are unchanged across an exec.  Then you can map it in the child.  Alternatively, investigate APIs like shm_open()/shm_unlink() which will manage a global file mapping such that other processes can use it, not just a child.

But basically: you have to mmap() in the child, you can't pass anything in your address space to the child in Unix.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to share a structure? Should I implement it as text in the shared file? or is this possible:`struct Costume_Struct* my_struct;` and then in the processes `addr = mmap(NULL, length, prot, flags, fd, offset); Costume_Struct* proc_struct = (Costume_Struct*) addr` ?

Comment: Yes, you can put structs (but not C++ objects, at least without great care to make sure they are "POD") in the shared memory.  It will work exactly as you think it will; it's just m emory.

Comment: Many Thanks! What about my last question? -> Since every process needs at least one I/O operation to mmap the file, is there any faster approach?

Comment: Doing an exec inherently involves many mmap operations (at the very least ld-linux.so and the executable .text segment, dynamic binaries have many more).  Adding one more is not a meaningful overhead IMHO.

Comment: Maybe I didn't clearly convey my meaning. I mean, this approach comes with an "open file" operation which is an I/O operation. Is there any other way to start from the memory itself rather than memory mapping a file?

Comment: Again, "open file" is a fast operation that is already done multiple times underneath every exec.  Adding one really isn't a problem that I can see.  Rather, if it is, your problem is likely that you're trying to exec **at all** and not with the shared memory mechanism.  Have you investigated things like `clone()` with non-standard arguments to allow you to spawn vm-isolated children that start from the parent's memory state?

Comment: Alright. I got your point. Thanks ver much. I will take a look at it as well.